# How to get all the values by keys that is within a range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {8.12: 4, 6.93: 2, 6.78: 2, 7.04: 2, 7.21: 2, 8.05: 4, 7.48: 2, 
        6.52: 0, 6.95: 2, 7.28: 2, 7.56: 2, 6.67: 0, 6.33: 2, 6.37: 1, 
        7.15: 1, 8.16: 5, 7.84: 3, 7.13: 2, 6.24: 0, 7.11: 3}
```

I want to get all the values by key that is in range +- 1. For example, how can I get all that values that the key value is between 7 and 9.

```
x = 8
print dict[range(x-1,x+1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```py
for key in dict.keys():
    if key >= x-1 and key <= x+1:
        print dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [dict[i] for i in dict.keys() if i > x-2 and i < x+2]
```

[image]

Comment: This will only work if the keys are integers, use >=x-1 and <=x+1 instead

Comment: @Nicolas can you please review screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand what i should review here, the code is working but you did neither use a value x which was part of the question nor did you use the margin of +-1 given in the question.

My comment was about using > x-2 is different from using >=x-1 as long as there are values existing that are larger than x-2 but smaller than x-1 --> if there are non-integer (so float) values used as key.

Answer (score 0):

Using **comprehenssion**, in a pythonic way :

```
x=8
print([dict[key] for key in dict if x+1 >= key >= x-1])
```